# VI Ctrl+W terminal Alternative

Tags: display, terminal, vi

Is there a mouse control short cut to Ctrl+W, like Option+click, to go to any screen directly? 
I dont want to cycle through all windows, instead want to directly go to say 7th screen, of the 10 split screens, instead of doing Ctrl W 7 times. Option+click only works within the screen. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation* has information on [moving the cursor between windows windows, see `:help window-move-cursor`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window-move-cursor).

## How to jump to a specific window

Prefix the <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd> `movement` command with a number.

eg, to jump to the third window down, prefix with 3:

```
3^Wj
```

### Example

Create some windows, move 5 down, 3 up, 4 down etc:

[image]

Key sequence:

```
:split @: @@ @@ @@ @@ @@ @@ @@ @@ 5^wj 3^wk 4^wj
```

<sup><sup>*</sup> Your question seems to be about vi, and this documentation pertains to **vim**; unfortunately I don't have a copy of vi handy to test at present</sup>